# Bootstrap contact form to email address

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, email

I have a bootstrap template with a built in contact form (code below). What is the best way to set it up to receive the form contacts on a specific email address?

```
<section id="contact" class="single-page scrollblock">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="align"><i class="icon-uniF0E0"></i></div>
    <h1>Contact us now!</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span12">
        <div class="cform" id="theme-form">
          <form action="#" method="post" class="cform-form">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="span6"> <span class="your-name">
                <input type="text" name="your-name" placeholder="Your Name" class="cform-text" size="40" title="your name">
                </span> </div>
              <div class="span6"> <span class="your-email">
                <input type="text" name="your-email" placeholder="Your Email" class="cform-text" size="40" title="your email">
                </span> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="span12"> <span class="message">
                <textarea name="message" class="cform-textarea" cols="40" rows="10" title="drop us a line."></textarea>
                </span> </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="submit" value="Send message" class="cform-submit pull-right">
            </div>
            <div class="cform-response-output"></div>
          </form>
        </div>
       </div>
      <!-- ./span12 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
  </section>
```

Comment: 1. Pick a server side language that you like and your server supports. 2. Learn how to send email with that language.

Answer (score 0):

You can not send emails on client-side, you will have to submit the form back to the server, where you need to have some kind of software running that can send the emails for you. That software can be Node.js or PHP or something else. If you were to choose PHP, you could for example put a file named 'send_email.php' in the same folder as your form, with the contents

```
<?php

$message = "Mail from " . $_POST['your-name'] . " <" . $_POST['your-email'] . ">\r\n\r\n" . $_POST['message'];

mail('my.email@example.com', 'Subject', $message);
```

then, in your form, change

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="cform-form">
```

to

```
<form action="send_email.php" method="post" class="cform-form">
```

And that's all it takes, assuming you have the PHP framework up and running on your server. See http://php.net/manual/en/install.php for more information on how to accomplish that.